# mosquitto fail to start when password authentication is configured

Tags: authentication, mosquitto

I have mosquitto perfectly running on a Raspberry Pi ***till*** I configure the password authentication.

Here is the error I have when launching mosquitto :

```
> pi@pi3:/etc/systemd/system $ systemctl status mosquitto.service
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-04-02 11:29:12 CEST; 18s ago
       Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
             man:mosquitto(8)
    Process: 1178 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
    Process: 1179 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
    Process: 1180 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1181 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1182 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, st>
   Main PID: 1182 (code=exited, status=3)
        CPU: 64ms
>
>Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
...skipping...
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-04-02 11:29:12 CEST; 18s ago
       Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
             man:mosquitto(8)
    Process: 1178 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
    Process: 1179 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
    Process: 1180 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1181 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1182 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, st>
   Main PID: 1182 (code=exited, status=3)
        CPU: 64ms
>
>Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
...skipping...
● mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-04-02 11:29:12 CEST; 18s ago
       Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
             man:mosquitto(8)
    Process: 1178 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
    Process: 1179 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
    Process: 1180 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1181 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1182 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, st>
   Main PID: 1182 (code=exited, status=3)
        CPU: 64ms
>
>Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
~
~
~
~
~
>
>pi@pi3:/etc/systemd/system $ journalctl -xe
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mosquitto.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mosquitto.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit mosquitto.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 2938 and the job result is done.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mosquitto.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 11:29:12 pi3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mosquitto.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mosquitto.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 2938 and the job result is failed.
```

Here are my configuration files : The information from [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/) is slitghly different from the info in the README...

```
pi@pi3:/etc/mosquitto $ cat mosquitto.conf 
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883
pi@pi3:/etc/mosquitto $ ls conf.d
harold.conf  notsecur.conf  README
```

Does anybody get an idea what could be wrong on my setup ?

Does these info help ?

```
pi@pi3:/etc/mosquitto/conf.d $ sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
1680461082: Loading config file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/harold.conf
1680461082: Error: Unknown configuration variable      "harold:$7$101$FQZWHiGkvnVWZKHs$vaiDEiJh09sH/KTRF7gOR4rFnn5hEbvBXqAMJFF  P74BHtg==".
1680461082: Error found at /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/harold.conf:1.
1680461082: Error found at /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:13.


pi@pi3:/etc/mosquitto/conf.d $ sudo cat /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log | tail -20
1680446446: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1680446446: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1680446446: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1680446446: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
1680447269: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1680447269: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1680447269: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1680447269: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1680447269: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
1680449361: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1680451162: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1680452963: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1680454764: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1680456565: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1680458366: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1680460167: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto//mosquitto.db.
1680461035: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1680461035: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1680461035: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1680461035: Error: Address already in use
```

The file harold.conf has been generated witj the command :
mosquitto_passwd -c harold.conf harold

```
pi@pi3:/etc/mosquitto/conf.d $ sudo cat harold.conf && cat notsecur.conf 
harold:$7$101$FQZWHiGkvnVWZKHs$...4BHtg==
#listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

I think the "per_listener_settings true" parameter was missing. I now made it to work. But the configuration is very tricky.

Comment: Without seeing either the content of the extra files in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` to see who you've configured things and the logs output in `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` to see the errors we are not going to be able to help here. Also if you run it manually with `sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` may show the error in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can not just include a username/password pair in the configuration file like that (`harold.conf`).

From the [mosquitto.conf](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) man page:

> *password_file* file path
>
> Set the path to a password file. If defined, the contents of the file are used to control client access to the broker. The file can be
> created using the mosquitto_passwd(1) utility. If mosquitto is
> compiled without TLS support (it is recommended that TLS support is
> included), then the password file should be a text file with each line
> in the format "username:password", where the colon and password are
> optional but recommended. If allow_anonymous is set to false, only
> users defined in this file will be able to connect. Setting
> allow_anonymous to true when password_fileis defined is valid and
> could be used with acl_file to have e.g. read only guest/anonymous
> accounts and defined users that can publish.

Username/password pairs need to be in their own specific file and be referenced from a config file as described above.

You need to rename and move the `harold.conf` file to `/etc/mosquitto/passwd` then edit the `notsecur.conf` to read:

```
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
allow_anonymous false
```

Setting `allow_anonymous false` will allow you to properly test that username/password supplied is correct.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any better. Since  "allow_anonymous false" is set, no connexion except localhost would work.

Comment: `allow_anonymous` does not have any impact on where can connect from, only if the connection needs to supply a username/password. If you want to be able to connect from a remote machine you must include `listener 1883` (but you already had that commented out in your earlier setup)